# Flag vs Close, when to use?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, vote-to-close

Today I voted to close on an off topic question, but this made me think, if I vote to close is the question also flagged too get the attention of other user's?, or should I also flag as a duplicate to get some attention to it ?

So the question is, does a close vote include a falg when I do it or should I do both ?

Comment: Flags are only seen by moderators so flagging doesn't really get attention to it. Voting to close puts it in the close queue and that does get attention to it. Flagging to close is only for users who don't have the rep to vote yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are a 3000+ user and try to flag a question to close, you automatically get redirected to close menu.

Actually you just cast a close vote. You can't do both.

Lower rep users can only flag.